# No funciona un programa de cifrado en Pyhon

Tags: python, python-3.x, encriptación, cifrado

Estoy intentando crear un programa, el cual se trata de cifrar sustituyendo los caracteres por un grupo de 3 caracteres aleatorios, para esto mi profesor me dijo que usara dos listas, una para los caracteres y otra para las claves. Me funciona a la perfección al encriptar, pero al intentar descifrar solo sirve con los 3 primeros caracteres y luego tira valores incorrectos.

Aquí está lo que he hecho

```
codigo = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," ",",","."]

claves = ["1j4", "2ba"," u7s", "js7", "py7",
      "k10", "xp1", "w10", "2j9", "78u",
      "huj", "7j2", "je3", "zi7", "kyc",
      "pj8", "km7", "8i0", "00o", "mu7",
      "tr5", "i64", "1jp", "ñj1", "68q",
      "ma3", "jy0", " ", "lo8", "xc2",
    ]
def cifrar():
mensaje = input("\nIngrese el mensaje a cifrar: ")

mensaje = mensaje.lower()

cifrado = ""

for i in mensaje:
    pos = codigo.index(i)
    if i in codigo:
        cifrado+=claves[pos]

print(f"\nEl mensaje encriptado es: {cifrado} ")

def descifrar():
cifrado = input("\nIngrese el mensaje a decifrar: ")
cifrado = cifrado.lower()

mensaje = ""

for i in cifrado:
    pos = cifrado.index(i)
    caracteres = cifrado[pos:pos+3]
    if caracteres in claves:
        nueva_pos=claves.index(caracteres)
        mensaje+=codigo[nueva_pos]

print(f"\nEl mensaje original es: {mensaje}")
```

No sé por qué ocurre esto, ya que cuando encripto la palabra "hol" y lo reviso y está bien, pero al desencriptarla solo me tira "hol" y así con otras palabras, llegando a veces a tirar valores incorrectos.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del `for` que utilizas para recorrer el mensaje y descifrarlo, tiene un pequeño problema, que impide obtener la palabra devuelta correctamente, ya que `i` tendría que tomar el valor de la posición que se encuentra cada 3 espacios en cada iteración.

`i` en este caso va tomando letra por letra, por lo cual al momento de encontrar la clave entra en conflicto, ejemplo:

La palabra `paralelepipedo` es igual a `km71j400o1j47j2py77j2py7km72j9km7py7js7pj8` cifrado

```py
for i in cifrado:
    pos = cifrado.index(i)
    caracteres = cifrado[pos:pos+3]
```

En la primera iteración, cuando este en **k** tomará los primeros 3 caracteres correctamente, es decir, **km7**, pero como `i` no se puede modificar en el loop `for`, al entrar al segundo ciclo `i` sera igual a **m** por lo cual tomará los 3 caracteres que siguen, es decir, **m71**.

---

Ahora bien como no se puede modificar el índice de un ciclo `for`, puedes hacer lo mismo con un ciclo `while`:

```py
    i = 0
    while i < len(cifrado):
        if cifrado[i] != " ": #si es que no es un espacio en blanco
            caracteres = cifrado[i:i+3] #obtiene 3 caracteres
        else:
            caracteres = cifrado[i] # obtiene el espacio en blanco
        if caracteres in claves:
            nueva_pos=claves.index(caracteres)
            mensaje+=codigo[nueva_pos]
        if cifrado[i] != " ": #si no es un espacio en blanco
            i = i+3 #aumenta 3
        else:
            i = i + 1 #aumenta 1
```

`i` aumentará de 3 en 3 a no ser que sea un espacio en blanco, en ese caso, solo aumentará en una unidad obteniendo el cifrado correctamente.

***Acotación***

Como bien menciona [@JohanC](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/149571/johanc) la clave de la letra **c** contiene un espacio adicional, por lo mismo esta letra en el descifrado no coincidiría, dado a esto la clave debería ser **"u7s"**, en lugar de **" u7s"**, es decir, sin el espacio.

Comment: Cuidado con palabras con "c". La clave es " u7s", incluído el espacio.

Comment: @JohanC tienes razón, por ende la clave debería ir sin el espacio para que este funcione bien :)